# why setresuid / setresgid works different in Python versus C

Tags: python, c, setuid

It some experiments it seems that setresuid / setresgid works differently in C versus Python and I don't quite know why. If I have the following short C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    setresuid(999, 999, 999);
    setresgid(999, 999, 999);
    system("/some/program");
    return 0;
}
```

And the binary has the setuid bit set and the binary is in group 999 and owner 999, running this binary as another user will run /some/program as user 999 which is what you would expect as I believe the idea behind the setuid bit is to allow a program to be run with the group / owner permissions of the file.

On the other hand, if I have the following short Python program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import subprocess

os.setresuid(999,999,999)
subprocess.check_output('/some/program', shell=True)
```

and the python script has the setuid bit set, is in group 999 and owned by user 999, running the script as another user gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/foo/bar/sample.py", line 5, in <module>
    os.setresuid(999,999,999)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Any idea why this might be?

Comment: Yes, the Python script has the setuid bit set as well. I updated my description.

Comment: My guess is the Python runtime complains about invalid operations whereas the C syscalls just returns -1. Can you print the return value of `setresuid()`?

Comment: You might prefer to ask something like: "how can I grant system privileges to a python program similar to how I would `setuid` a compiled binary?" because now your question is answered but you probably still have a problem that needs to be solved.

Answer (score 4):

Executing an interpreted script is different from executing a compiled binary. In the case of an interpreted script, what is actually being execed is the interpreter, not the script itself. For this reason, `setuid` on a script does not have any affect. You have to `setuid` the interpreter, which is `python` in this case. This is not recommended.

Comment: Filesystem capabilities eg `CAP_SETUID` may work on scripts.

Comment: This seems plausible but it is interesting that the usual user and group permissions for actually running the script would be respected but the setuid functionality is not. If setuid would have to be set on the interpreter and not the script why do permissions work at all at the script level?

Comment: @blischalk i'm super late to the party here, but that's because for scripts, it has to do with *reading* the scripts.

consider the difference. to do `./script.py`, script.py must be at LEAST 0500.
however, to do `python ./script.py`, script.py can be at 0400.

there's no way (unless you're root! or have the parser itself be suid) to execute a script, either standalone or as input to a parser, without at LEAST read permissions - because it's operating on the *content* of the script, not the *execution* of the script. (sort of.)

does that help?